# Why it is prompting for input after executing mail command in unix

Tags: bash, email

```
#!/bin/bash
### script to send email with attachment ###
### Declare Email Subject

SUBJECT="TESTING EMAIL"

## Declare Reciever's Email Id

EMAIL="reciever@testemail.com"

## Declare CopyTo Email Id

COPYTO_EMAIL=copyto@testemail.com
destfile="/home/acer/text.txt"

## Removing output files of the script from previous run

rm -f out.mail

## Remove the message body and sent files used in previous versions

rm -f mailbody.txt
rm -f OUTPUTRESULT.CSV

## Create the mail body message in a text file
## Initialize the text file

cat  > mailbody.txt
echo "Hi User,\n" >> mailbody.txt
echo "The result file for the server - SERVERNAME - is attached with this email.\n" >> mailbody.txt
echo "\n\nRegards,\nAdmin" >>mailbody.txt

## Sending email using mail command

cat mailbody.txt > out.mail

# Copy the OUTPUT.CSV file generated to another file OUTPUT_RESULT.CSV

uuencode $destfile >> out.mail

# are in their respenter code hereective variables - $SUBJECT and $EMAIL.

mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" "$COPYTO_MAIL" < out.mail
echo "Email sent."
```

after executing  the mail command in this script, terminal is prompting for user input.
when i press ctrl+d only the msg Email sent is displayed.

It should not ask for user input.

what could i do?

can u tell me why it is prompting for user input?

Comment: Well it might be worth trying but add a line with a single dot at the end of your message. Something like "\n."

Answer (score 4):

What makes you think it's after the mail command that the terminal is prompting for user input? Have you actually traced it? (`bash -x`)

In my opinion, what's blocking you is this line:

```
cat  > mailbody.txt
```

It's blocking because in this context, `cat` reads from standard input to write to `mailbody.txt`, and since you haven't bound standard input to anything more specific, it's still reading from the terminal.

Comment: +1 The reason you see "Email sent" after hitting Ctrl-d is that everything between `cat > mailbody.txt` and `mail -s ...` happens with no visible output.

Answer (score 1):

The manpage *mail(1)* state the following on my system:

> **Sending mail**
>
> ```
> To send a message to one or more people, mail can be invoked with argu-
> ments which are the names of people to whom the mail will be sent.  You
> are then expected to type in your message, followed by a control-D ('^D')
> at the beginning of a line.  The section below, Replying to or
> originating mail, describes some features of mail available to help you
> compose your letter.
> ```

somehow you have to enter perhaps the *control-D*.

I had as well trouble sending email with `mail` or `mutt` from command line without user interaction. My workaround was to use the [php mail](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php) function from command line.

Something like this (not tested, just wrote from my mind):

```
php -r "mail('user@example.com', 'my subject', 'my body message');"
```